# How can I move a ui text up?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is a screenshot of the hierarchy I have a cube and a sphere child of the cube.
Then I have a canvas set to space world overlay and a UI text child of the canvas.

[image: Text ui]

I want the UI text to move with the Sphere.

When I'm running the game the text is in the center of the sphere but only the sphere is moving up the text stay at the same position. I tried also the other canvas modes screen space camera and world space but the text is not moving with the sphere.

This script is attached to the Sphere :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Testing : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject myText;
    public float speed;
    public float offset;
    public bool go = false;

    private bool exited = false;
    private Vector3 exitPosition;

    private void Start()
    {
        myText.GetComponent<Text>().alignment = (TextAnchor)TextAlignment.Center;

        Debug.Log("Position : " + transform.position);
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.name == "Cube")
        {
            Debug.Log("Exited !");
        }

        exitPosition = new Vector3(transform.position.x,
                transform.position.y + offset, transform.position.z);

        exited = true;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (go)
        {
            if (!exited)
            {
                transform.position += Vector3.up * speed * Time.deltaTime;
                myText.GetComponent<RectTransform>().position += Vector3.up * speed * Time.deltaTime;
            }
            else
            {
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, exitPosition, speed * Time.deltaTime);
                myText.GetComponent<RectTransform>().position = Vector3.MoveTowards(myText.transform.position, exitPosition, speed * Time.deltaTime);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried also to move the Canvas with the Text to be a child of the Sphere but still, the text is not moving.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to set the Canvas to `World Space` and then child the Canvas to your sphere.

The other option is to add a script to your UI object and have it convert to world space coordinates to follow the sphere. Something along the  lines of:

```
uiObject.transform.position = YourMainCamera.WorldToScreenPoint(theSphere.transform.position);
```

If you use the second option, do **not** change your canvas type and do **not** child the object. It will change the position of your object to appear over the sphere based on the world position relative to the camera you are using.

I should also add, with either of these two solutions, delete **all** other code you are using to move the text.