# What is Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint means?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is that the same as changing a Canvas in the editor to World Space mode and then drag a Camera ?
Is this the same as Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint in script ?

[image]

I want to position a UI text above any object either a cube or my player. I used a canvas with UI text and in the canvas I set the mode of the renderer to world space with a camera and it's working fine.

but in this tutorial she is using a small script with Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0bvDmqqMXcA

I wonder what is better to use or what is the correct way to do it ? Does it matter if I'm using world space in the canvas in the editor or using this small script with the Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint ?

Comment: Instead of asking a new question, you can add follow-up related questions to the comments of the answers on your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67552354/how-can-i-move-a-ui-text-up).

Answer (score 1):

I would say its just the same and that you can do it the way you like it better. If the canvas component already has an option so that you can select in which space you want the canvas rendered in, I would go for that. With that option the same transformation will take place as the one with `Camera.WorldToScreenPoint`. Different ways to do the same thing.

According to the order of transformation in computer graphics, the tranformation to the screen space is the last one.

[image]

If you could skip or safe some transformation due to the fact that you could be making it 2 times to work in a determined space, it would be important to consiration to make but in this case I think its not.

For example if you wanted the canvas in the world space and you were setting the canvas render mode to the screen space and then, moving it to the world with `Camera.cameraToWorldMatrix`, that would not make sense because you would be doing 4 extra transformation uselessly, 2 transformations to go from the world space to the screen space, and another 2 to go back to the world space.

You can give a read to the spaces topics in computer graphics [here](http://findnerd.com/list/view/Computer-Graphics-Different-Spaces/6982/) or [here](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/). Its a deep topic, but worth to make an effort to try to understand it if you are into computer graphics.

Answer (score 0):

See [`Camera.WorldToScreenPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToScreenPoint.html)

> Transforms position from world space into screen space.
>
> Screenspace is defined in pixels. The bottom-left of the screen is (0,0); the right-top is (pixelWidth,pixelHeight). The z position is in world units from the camera.

(Didn't watch the video but) Your canvas is most probably a `Screenspace Overlay`. Such a canvas uses - as the name suggests - **Screenspace** pixel coordinates.

What you script does is taking a Unity 3D world coordinate of the object and convert it to the according 2D pixel space coordinate. It is simply used to translate between these two coordinate systems.

Why? - Because this way you can place a 2D UI element in the Canvas to the same 2D pixel screenspace position where the 3D world space object is being rendered to.

---

The alternative to that would be to e.g. make your Canvas rather a `Worldspace` and position your UI elements just like normal objects. **BUT** this also means that all the UI content in this Canvas is affected by the Cameras perspective rendering so e.g. Text that is far away will be smaller etc.